# The caller does not have permission when attempting to use Google Cloud Storage within Cloud Run

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-iam

I'm attempting to get a Node project setup on Google Cloud Run with Cloud Storage. I am running into an authentication issue when using a created Service Account.

When creating the service account I did successfully download the JSON token and got everything running correctly in my local development environment.

The issue is when I have the application deployed successfully to Cloud Run I get the following error:
`Error: The caller does not have permission`

This occurs when I am attempting to get a signed URL for uploading files to a Storage Bucket.

I create the Storage client like this:

```js
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");
const storage = new Storage();
```

...and further down in my script the call is like this:

```
const [url] = await storage
  .bucket(bucketName)
  .file(filename)
  .getSignedUrl(options);
```

I have setup the the following permissions for the IAM Service Account:

- **Cloud SQL Client** - Maybe relevant? I have Cloud SQL successfully working on deployed environment.
- **Service Account User** - Needed to be used as a Service Account?
- **Storage Object Creator** - I only need the ability to create signed upload urls from this project.

I have also assigned the mentioned service account to the Cloud Run instance via the console.

Just to confirm, the application runs 100% correctly locally using the Service Account JSON Key, it's just not working when running in the Google Cloud.

Comment: And you are sure that the Cloud Run service is configured to use the same service account you are using locally, rather than the default one?

Comment: @VilleRinne Yes, I have specified the "Service account" to the created non-default one. I can see it on the details tab of the revision.

Comment: I'm not sure if this has any relevance. This is the contents of my Dockerfile
`
    FROM node:alpine
    WORKDIR /usr/app/src
    COPY package*.json ./
    RUN npm install --production
    COPY src .
    CMD ["node", "index.js"]
`

Answer (score 33):

I managed to resolve the issue. It looks like when deployed into Cloud Run it also requires the extra permission "Service Account Token Creator" to run `getSignedUrl`. Locally for some reason this role is not required.

To add this role, go to IAM & Admin section in the Google Cloud Console, edit the "App Engine default service account" and add the "Service Account Token Creator" role. Click Save and that should be it.

Comment: This is the case as well for App Engine Standard environment. If you are utilizing the default service account, it will explicitly need the  "Service Account Token Creator" permission in IAM. Also, note that it seemed to take 5 minutes to take effect.

Comment: I'll upvote this if someone can explain how to set the "Service Account Token Creator" permission on Google Cloud Run. I can't figure it out.

Comment: -open "https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam"

-edit your "App Engine default service account" 

-add new role "Service Account Token Creator"

Comment: I had to add the 'Service Account Token Creator' permission to the 'Compute Engine default service account' since that is the one Cloud Run seems to use by default.

Comment: I tried the "Default compute service account" and it didn't work. Then I tried the "App Engine default service account" and it worked.

Comment: This also allowed me to use ADC with Gitlab Runner.