# Permissions Denied on getSignedUrl Promise in Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have an http onCall cloud function which I want to return a signedURL to allow me to upload a file to a cloud storage bucket [Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817559/cant-resolve-getsignedurl-promise-in-cloud-function/62818690#62818690)

It keeps telling me permission is denied, but I can't see where the problem could be. The function GCPSecureURL is set to Allow unauthenticated, and StorageAdmin is set to all users.

A service account also has access to StorageAdmin on the bucket, because a pub/sub subscribes to the event when a file is uploaded to the bucket and triggers a pdf conversion service.

Why can't I get the signedURL back from the function?

Right now the promise is pending, then the console logs a POST 500 error. The logs for the function say Unhandled error { Error: The caller does not have permission" ...

Comment: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62479994/the-caller-does-not-have-permission-when-attempting-to-use-google-cloud-storage) looks very similar although it concerns Cloud Run. Tty adding "Service Account Token Creator" role to your service account.

Comment: I was confused tho - it looks like you can't upload new files at all with signedURL because it doesn't accept POST - yet the example I've been trying to adapt specifically is for uploading? Has this changed since signedURLs were implemented?

Comment: I don't think anything changed, you should still be able to upload files. Can you elaborate more on how you performing the upload and what error you get. Also check [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#signing-resumable)

Comment: OK I added Service Account Token Creator role to the correct service account and it now works - thank you so much!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was also getting the `Service Account Token Creator` error when calling `file.getSignedUrl()`.

I fixed it by visiting the [IAM Permissions](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam) page for my Firebase project and editing the `App Engine default service account` to have the `Service Account Token Creator` role.

Comment: Does not work in firebase-functions v2 / cloud run v2 :'(