# getSignedURL() called from firebase cloud function gives permission denied error ( firebase-functions v2)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I need to download html pages only for authenticated users, pages are stored in "Firebase Storage" as html.

I get the right action by using the bellow firebase cloud function (v2) (getReportForUser) using getDownloadURL() (commented-out) , the problem is that users can share files, which I want to avoid, so I switched to use getSignedURL() that will give the user a limited time to download the file, but I got Error: `Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob' denied on resource (or it may not exist).`

Is this the right approach to authenticate downloading files, and is yes, how can we resolve this error please?

```
exports.getReportForUser = onCall({ region: ["europe-west1"] }, async (request) => {

    const getReportURLsync = () => {
        return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
            // Get a reference to index.html file in storage bucket
            const fileRef = getStorage().bucket("wa-connect").file("reports/" + "index.html");
            resolve(await fileRef.getSignedUrl({version: "v4", action: "read", expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 2, })); // expires in 2 minutes
            //resolve( await getDownloadURL(fileRef));

        }
    )}
    
    async function getReportURL(serial, timestamp) {
        return await getReportURLsync(serial, timestamp);
    }

    try {
        return { reportURL: await getReportURL() };
    } catch (err) {
        info("Error caught in getReportForUser code: ", "->", err);
    }
});
```

I also tried the accepted answer in [Permissions Denied on getSignedUrl Promise in Cloud Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62880196/permissions-denied-on-getsignedurl-promise-in-cloud-function) but it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Both a download URL and a signed URL give public access to the file, which is not what you want.

Instead you'll want to [use the SDK to download the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_directly_from_the_sdk) with its `getBlob`, `getBytes` and `getStream` method. These methods all give authorized users access to the data in the file, without using a public URL.

Comment: HTML reports contain many links, scripts, fonts, and many assets, so they cannot be downloaded to our web-based clients. All we want to do is get the URL of the html report file which is stored in Firebase Storage, and then clients can view the file on computers there, so ***getBlob, getBytes*** doesn't do that job, am I right?

Comment: I know that (signed URL give public access) but for a limited time, which may suit our needs.

Comment: Both download URLs and signed URLs provide read-only **public** access. Since you say you need to  download html pages **only for authenticated users**, they are not an option.

Comment: We need the URL no matter whether it is public or private, as we can release it for a limited time, the question is how can we use 'getSignedUrl' in Firebase Cloud function.
 The above code is supposed to do the job, but it throws the following exception 'Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob' denied on resource (or it may not exist)'?